# insert DateTime string into datetime field in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using PHP to insert records into BigQuery but having a problem trying to insert the a value in the datetime column called PageView_Date. Is our format not correct?

**DATA WE INSERT**

[PageView_ID] => 31580396
[PageView_Date] => 2016-12-17 17:16:27

**BIGQUERY RESPONSE**

[reason] => invalid
[location] => pageview_date
[debugInfo] => generic::out_of_range: Mismatch between format character 'T' and string character ' '
[message] => Mismatch between format character 'T' and string character ' '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that the datetime value has that format? The error message indicates that it contains a `T` separating the date from the time part, e.g. `2016-12-17T17:16:27`. You may be interested in [this feature request from the public tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=842), which despite referring to parameters would apply to JSON parsing as well, for instance.

Comment: I was able to get the date inserted by replacing the space with a T so "2016-12-17 17:16:27" became "2016-12-17T17:16:27" and it worked. As the link you pointed out I tried all different formats and this just didnt seem like one we should use.

Comment: I was missing the "t" as well. Thx